# How can access multi Lists from Sharepoint Add-ins?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I creating a SharePoint-hosted Add-ins.

I want access multi Lists in web host:

[image]

But it only `Trust It` a `List`

How can allow select multi `List` to `Trust It`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you could grant permissions to your add-ins on the web level. Thus your add-ins would have permissions to all the lists in web host:

[image]

[image]